# Obtaining number of errors in template with template tags

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to use a template tag to only show certain html if the form doesn't load with errors. I've got this in def clean():

**forms.py**

```py
home_zipcode = cleaned_data.get('home_zipcode')
if ' ' in home_zipcode:
    self.add_error('home_zipcode', "Please remove all spaces from the Zip Code.")            
    raise forms.ValidationError('Please review the errors below.')
```

**template**

```
{% if no errors %}

   some html

{% endif %}
```

Do you know what template tag I would use to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check if `form.errors` is "falsy", dictionaries are "falsy" if they do not have any entries

```
{% if not form.errors %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```html
{% if form.errors|length == 0 %}

  some html

{% endif %}
```